# How to display all the 'name' values in this json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, object

```
let url = 'api url';

const players = [];
fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
 .then(data => players.push(data.included));

console.log(players);
```

I am using an api to view players on a server. My output:

```
https://imgshare.io/image/NyvUN5
```

I want to display all the name value of all current players.
the number of objects in this array can be different at any time.

Comment: imgshare.io - no way.

Comment: Can you add the actual output code here instead of an `img` please.

Comment: ^ [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the players array and then access the properties of each player:

```
for (var player in players) {
    console.log(player.attributes.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let url = 'api url';

const players = [];
fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => players = data.map(v=>v.attributes.name));
```

I can fail because imgshare instead copypast json.